# Angular Mat-Toggle with changed background

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have Mat-Toggle buttons used in the `legacy` mode. I change the background color for the focus mode. This works fine.

[image]

But when I change the selection via keyboard back to the initially focused button the background color of the `scss` files is not any longer applied. (`.mat-button-toggle-checked.cdk-focused`)

[image]

How to set the background properly?

Sample code provided in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wbjjkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-exclusive-example.scss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicked with the mouse: 
[image: when selected with mouse]

When tabbed with the keyboard (Now shows with background-color as expected):
[image: when tabbed with keyboard]

Please find my solution on the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-62509831?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-exclusive-example.scss)
button-toggle-exclusive-example.scss

```
.example-selected-value {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-purple: mat-palette($mat-teal);
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-purple);

$config: mat-typography-config();
@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {
  .mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: mat-color($app-purple, 400);
     @extend .text-color;
  }
  .mat-button-toggle-checked.cdk-focused { 
  background-color: mat-color($app-purple, 600);
    @extend .text-color;
  }
  .mat-button-toggle-checked.mat-button-toggle-disabled {
    background-color: mat-color($app-purple, 200);
    color: mat-color($app-purple, default-contrast);
  }
}

.text-color {
  * {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

// Include the mixin
@include mix-app-theme($app-theme);
```

I've amended your code slightly to include a new class to change the color of the button when it's in a cdk-focused state.

I've included the * selector has an override to mitigate changing the background color.  There seems to be a bug with the mat-button-toggle when trying to change the cdk-focus color.

I'll try to dig further to see why this is happening.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In principal it works - although the whole Material Theme customize sounds like a mystical cloudy mountain. The `@extend` is something I never read before. It seems like I need it **ONLY** for the `cdk-focused`. It works as well for the `standard` appearance (as one would expect). Thx a lot. I'm still unclear if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: Hi @LeO the '@extend' is just a way to extend another class in SCSS, you don't have to use it, you could just write styles in the class instead.  https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#example-1-scss

I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently an element causing this with class
`mat-button-toggle-focus-overlay`.

This element is inside each toggle button and produces an overlay of background white to appear in front of your background.

You can set this class opacity to `0 !important`, but then the visual focus when switching buttons with keyboard will fail.

You could set it to `0 !important` programmatically when the related button is `(click)` and then remove it when another button is `(click)`.